# Lifeboat vs bailout

Tags: banking, definition

I have encountered the term *lifeboat* in these two contexts:

- [Floating a “lifeboat”: The Banque de France and the crisis of 1889](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0304393214000737)
- [The 1974 rescue in the UK's secondary-banking crisis](https://books.google.com/books?id=-H_RAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA163&dq=%22lifeboat%20operation%22).

Is the term *lifeboat* exactly the same as *bailout*, but just less commonly used? Or are *lifeboats* some special subset of *bailouts*?

Comment: I'd be impressed if either has a technical meaning. [Bailout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailout) has a wikipedia page, while "lifeboat" doesn't (not an economics one). Since the authors of the "lifeboat" paper are French, I assume it's some kind of [calque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calque).

Comment: The "lifeboat" to the BoF was a [one-off thing](https://voxeu.org/article/banque-de-france-s-1889-lifeboat-bank-rescue) so in that case I don't see any difference from bailout.